# Modify parent controller state when loading child state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, treeview, angular-ui-router

I have this code for my `$stateProvider`

```
.state('app.parent', {
    url: '/app/:idParent',
    controller : "ParentController",
    resolve: {
      idParent : function($stateParams){
        return $stateParams.idParent
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.parent.child', {
    url: '/:idChild',
    resolve: {
      idChild : function($stateParams){
        return $stateParams.idChild;
      }
    }
  })
```

In the parent view I have a treeview and in child view I have information about the node selected in parent's treeview. The node's id is $stateParams.idChild

To show selected node I use

```
ng-class="{'bg-gray' : parentCtrl.idSelected == node.id}"
```

I want to select a node in the parent based on path idChild:

1. By clicking

   - I create a click function in parent controller to set `parentCtrl.idSelect = node.id`
   - And using `$state.go()`
   - So it worked
2. By refreshing

   - So, when it gets to state for path `/app/1/2`, it selects node with id 2.
   - How?

---

Well, I found a solution... 
I just don't know if is a good one...

I create an activate function in Child Controller and called

```
function ChildController($scope, idChild) {
    activate();

    function activate(){
        $scope.parentCtrl.idSelected = idChild;
    }
}
```

Is there a way without using $scope?
And it seems wrong using child controller to modify parent's state. Right?

Comment: In your child view's controller you can inject both `idParent` and `idChild`.
Just inject them and use as you with. I don't see any problem in your question. What exactly you cannot do? Show more code.

Comment: I don't have a child controller. I could. But the parent controlller has the logic to manipulate treeview. Not the child controller.

Comment: Hm.. So why you have child state at all? You can use `url: '/app/:idParent/:idChild'` as your parent url.

Comment: Because it has a child state.

```/app/:idParent``` -> shows root info
```/app/:idParent/:idChild``` -> shows node info

When I enter ```/app/:idParent``` I want to be able to edit root info.


when I enter ```/app/:idParent/:idChild``` I want to be able to edit node info, which view and state are different from root.

Comment: If I understand you correctly your problem is highlight treeview's node in parent view corresponding to current child view? If yes then you can define child state's controller, inject `idChild` into it and do something like `$scope.parentCtrl.idSelect = idChild`. But this approach relies on scope inheritance which I don't like.

Comment: YEAH! That is the edit I made... And I don't like the $scope too...

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If all what you need is to hightlight active item in parent state then you can use `ui-sref-active` like this

```
    <!-- This <li> will only add the 'bg-gray' class if 'app.parent.child' or its descendants are active
         AND if it is the link for the active child (aka idChild) -->
    <li ng-repeat="node in nodes" ui-sref-active="bg-gray">

      <!-- Here's a ui-sref that is also providing necessary parameters -->
      <a ui-sref="app.parent.child({idChild:node.id})">{{node.name}}</a>
    </li>
```

In this case you don't need your click handler at all. The class will be added as soon as child state will be activated.

I also recommend you to check this official ui-router [sample application](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/) and it's [sources](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/gh-pages/sample). It contains many useful tricks.